# Почему сайт автоматически перезагружается на iOS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, обработка-ошибок

Есть [сайт](https://vk.cc/6Wcyfj). Если его открывать на iPhone или iPad, то страница автоматически перезагружается. Браузер выдает сообщение "При работе с этой страницей произошел сбой, поэтому она была перезагружена". Можно ли это исправить? Вес всего сайта - 4.5 Мб.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Чтобы просматривать эту страницу, нужно зайти на сайт.`

Comment: С вами и не поспоришь :-) Чтобы посмотреть какой-то сайт, на него нужно зайти.

Comment: IPhone 6 16gb ничего такого

Comment: В отличие от Chrome, Safari выдает в консоли ошибку CORS на yandex метрику. Возможно, с этим и связана перезагрузка страницы. Уберите метрику на время и посмотрите, что получится.

Comment: Почему ссылку на сайт через vk.cc вставили?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

О причинах можно найти ответы через поиск Google, например, [вот](http://ipadstory.ru/pri-rabote-s-etoj-veb-stranicej-proizoshyol-sboj-poetomu-ona-byla-perezagruzhena.html) и [вот](https://akket.com/iphone-ipad/16028-pri-rabote-s-etoy-veb-stranitsey-proizoshel-sboy-v-safari-chto-eto-takoe.html).

**Решение проблемы**

Сайт давно запущен? Эта проблема обнаружилась только сейчас? Исходя из последних изменений можно быстрее выявить причину.

Так происходит при каждом обновлении страницы или только при первой загрузки (чтобы убрать из причины статику, что грузится один раз: js, картинки, css (анимация)).

Посмотрел код и производительность на стороне клиента — особых проблем не увидел.

**JS**

У вас есть доступ к редактированию кода сайта? Попробуйте без вреда для пользователя «отключить» (закомментировать) скрипты (js) и попорядку их раскомментировать: сначала один, перезагрузить/открыть страницу — если всё ок — то продолжить.

**CSS**

Если проблема не исчезла — проверьте CSS анимацию. Также закомментируйте файл /css/animate.css и перезагрузите/откройте сайт.

Вообщем «отключяя» и подключая файлы (js и css) постепенно, не забывая открывать/перезагружать страницу.

Без вреда для пользователей можно сделать (сайт у вас на PHP вижу), например, через:

```php
<?php if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != 'ваш IP') { ?>
    // тут что для вас скрываем, а не для пользователей
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Ваши ссылки изучил еще до публикации вопроса. Никакой рекламы на странице нет. Страница не является тяжелой. все картинки оптимизированы. Ссылка через ВК, чтобы не индексировалась на этой странице.

Comment: @ВикторПавлов не по теме по отвечу: сокращенные ссылки прекрасно индексируются и передают ссылочный вес. Но на Stack Overflow для всех ссылок выставляется атрибут: rel="nofollow noreferrer", что как бы указывает поисковым роботам не следовать по этой ссылке (nofollow)...

Comment: @ВикторПавлов ссылки на возможные причины я указал в первую очередь не для вас, а для тех пользователей, которые возможно попадут на эту страницу через поиск — чтобы была возможность сразу прочитать причины (для удобства). А ниже для вас и для пользователей исходя из причин ошибки — способы как можно найти причину, как я это вижу.